# Como configurar proxy no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy

Empresa onde trabalho aderiu o uso de proxy e estou tendo problemas para utilizar o `gradle`.

O gradle retorna o seguinte erro :

> Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Alguém já precisou realizar essa configuração?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consegui realizar a configuração do `proxy` através dos seguintes passos:

No Android Studio navegue até :

```
File > Settings > System Settings > HTTP Proxy
```

Dentro desse menu marque a opção `Manual proxy configuration` e selecione `HTTP`

**Host name :** "url do seu proxy"

**Port number:** "porta do seu proxy"

Caso seu proxy tenha usuário e senha você deve adicionar nos devidos campos `Login` e `password`.

Após seguir estes passos de `OK` e rode novamente o build no `gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho um detalhe para acrescentar.

Em alguns casos também será necessário configurar o HTTP**S**

Após a definição através do menu FILE>SETTINGS>HTTP PROXY, na primeira sincronização abrirá (caso setar o proxy manual) uma janela com as definições do proxy setado (apenas na primeira sincronização). Marque também a opção de HTTPS, uma vez que tal opção não estava disponível na primeira configuração.

Caso o problema persista selecione a opção SEM PROXY, aplique as alterações, e tente refazer a configuração de PROXY MANUAL, lembrando de marcar a opção de HTTPS na primeira execução.

Espero que seja útil.
Att., Daniel

Comment: Boa sacada, na época nem pensei nessa solução.